# Adding the NSObject to the a SKScene

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I recently making a racing game with using the SpriteKit. I create an NSObject class called "GameObject" to store all the properties, like physics. I also create another NSObject class called "GameWorld" to store all the game objects, like creating player objects and other objects with their location and the functions of the direction buttons. However, when I start to write a game scene class, I cannot add the world object to the scene, which means the car doesn't show up in the scene. Would anyone can help me about this question? The codes of my SKScene class is provided below,

```
@interface GamePlay : SKScene
@property (nonatomic) GameWorld *world;
-(void)update:(NSTimeInterval)currentTime;
-(id) initWithSize:(CGSize)s andWorld:(GameWorld *)w;
@end

@implementation GamePlay

- (id) initWithSize:(CGSize)s andWorld:(GameWorld *)w
{
    self = [super initWithSize:s];
    if (self)
    {
        _world = w;
    }
    return self;
}

-(void) didMoveToView:(SKView *)view
{
    if (!self.contentCreated ) {
        [self createSceneContents];
        self.contentCreated = YES;
    }
}

-(void) createSceneContents
{
    // turn off gravity for the world
    self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0.0f, 0.0f);
    self.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFit;

    //Create the background
    SKSpriteNode *background = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"road.png"];
    background.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));
    [self addChild:background];

    //Create the buttons for directions
    SKSpriteNode *up = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"Up.png"];
    up.position = CGPointMake(290, 115);
    up.name = @"upDirection";
    [self addChild:up];

    SKSpriteNode *down = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"Down.png"];
    down.position = CGPointMake(290, 40);
    down.name = @"downDirection";
    [self addChild:down];

    SKSpriteNode *left = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"Left.png"];
    left.position = CGPointMake(30, 40);
    left.name = @"leftDirection";
    [self addChild:left];

    SKSpriteNode *right = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"Right.png"];
    right.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), 40);
    right.name = @"rightDirection";
    [self addChild:right];

    // add objects from GameWorld to this scene using the world's worldNode property
    // Here is the place I confuse. the world doesn't show up 
    [self addChild:_world.worldNode];
}

//making buttons for the cars
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint positionInScene = [touch locationInNode:self];

    //setting a node to keep the position of each direction buttons
    SKNode *n = [self nodeAtPoint:positionInScene];

    NSLog(@"Node n:%@", n);
    //compare the location of each SKSpriteNode and the touch location
    SKNode *up = [self childNodeWithName:@"upDirection"];
    if (n == up) {
        [self.world goForward];
    }

    SKNode *down =[self childNodeWithName:@"downDirection"];
    if (n == down) {
        [self.world goBackward];
    }

    SKNode *left = [self childNodeWithName:@"leftDirection"];
    if (n == left) {
        [self.world goLeft];
    }

    SKNode *right = [self childNodeWithName:@"rightDirection"];
    if (n == right) {
        [self.world goRight];
    }
}

-(void)update:(NSTimeInterval)currentTime
{
    //I don't know how to start yet. = =
}

@end
```

The GameWorld Class is provided below:

```
@interface GameWorld : NSObject
@property (nonatomic) SKNode *worldNode;
@property (nonatomic) NSArray *gameObjs;
-(id)init;
-(void) initializeWorld;
-(void) goForward;
-(void) goBackward;
-(void) goLeft;
-(void) goRight;
@end

@implementation GameWorld

-(id)init
{
    if (self) {
        self = [super init];
        GameObject *player = [[GameObject alloc] initWithImageNamed:@"pCar.png" andPosition:CGPointMake(200, 85)];
        GameObject *otherCar = [[GameObject alloc]initWithImageNamed:@"AICar.png" andPosition:CGPointMake(200, 100)];

        _worldNode = [SKNode node];
        // now create the objects, put them in an SKNode
        // create the _worldNode with a size equal to the virtual world size
        // then add the game objects to that node
        _worldNode.scene.size = CGSizeMake(320, 480);
        _gameObjs = @[player, otherCar];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) initializeWorld
{
    // add skSpriteNodes to the worldNode
    SKSpriteNode *player = [[SKSpriteNode alloc] initWithImageNamed:@"pCar.png"];
    [_worldNode addChild:player];

    SKSpriteNode *otherCar = [[SKSpriteNode alloc] initWithImageNamed:@"AICar.png"];
    [_worldNode addChild:otherCar];
}

-(void) goForward
{
    GameObject *thePlayer = _gameObjs[1];
    thePlayer.node.position = CGPointMake(thePlayer.node.position.x, thePlayer.node.position.y + 10);
}

-(void) goBackward
{
    GameObject *thePlayer = _gameObjs[1];
    thePlayer.node.position = CGPointMake(thePlayer.node.position.x, thePlayer.node.position.y - 10);
}

-(void) goLeft
{
    GameObject *thePlayer = _gameObjs[1];
    thePlayer.node.position = CGPointMake(thePlayer.node.position.x - 10, thePlayer.node.position.y);
}

-(void) goRight
{
    GameObject *thePlayer = _gameObjs[1];
    thePlayer.node.position = CGPointMake(thePlayer.node.position.x + 10, thePlayer.node.position.y);
}

@end
```

Comment: Why are you subclassing from NSObject? You can subclass directly from SKNode, SKSpriteNode, or SKPhysicsWorld

Comment: oh, because I want to store all the objects and their properties in the NSObject class and I can just call the the NSObject class in the SKScene class and I would construct the game scene for me and no need to type repeated codes.

Comment: What you are describing is called Subclassing. FYI, SKNode is a subclass of NSObject, SKSpriteNode is a subclass of SKNode. Whatever you say you want to do with NSObject can and should be done using the appropriate SpriteKit class.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use `NSObject` is most cases. Use `SKNode` and `SKSpriteNode` instead. By subclassing these classes you can add your custom properties to them.

I suggest you the following structure of the project:

```
-- GameScene (SKScene)
---- BackgroundLayer (SKNode)
-------- BackgroundNode (SKSpriteNode)
---- UiLayer (SKNode)
-------- your buttons here... (SKSpriteNode)
---- CarLayer (SKNode)
-------- PlayerNode (SKSpriteNode)
-------- OtherCarNode (SKSpriteNode)
```

In this case you don't have to store objects in manually created arrays, such as `gameObjs`. For example, all buttons can be accessed from this property: `uiLayer.children`.

I have created a template, which I use for my Sprite Kit games, take a look on it:

https://github.com/andrew8712/spritekit-game-template

Comment: Oh thank you so much for your suggestions, but what if I have several scenes that uses this NSObject? Do I need to type them repeatedly in the different scene classes?